# Trying to create a pause button for JavaScript game

Tags: javascript, android, html

I have a little program that is like a Space Invaders game. I am trying to create a button that can pause the game when clicked and then also unpause when clicked.

I'm assuming that I will need a boolean variable that will say when paused = true and false however I'm not sure what to put inside of the if statement.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

Take look on this dummy example may be explain the idea for you

```
function pauseGame() {
if (!gamePaused) {
      game = clearTimeout(game);
      gamePaused = true;
} else if (gamePaused) {
      game = setTimeout(gameLoop, 1000 / 30);
      gamePaused = false;
}
}
```

and register the key to pause or button

```
function keyDown(e) {
     if (e.keyCode == 80) pauseGame();
}
```

feed me back in not obvious things

Comment: I understand the pauseGame function but what does the keyDown function do?

Comment: this function called when you press the key you want to pause the game , you can change it with button click event